# How to correctly align column containing both unicode character and empty list ()

Tags: common-lisp

I found that it is very difficult to align column if the row contains value which is a NIL

I try specified column width, however, in the output, NIL seems always has different width than other unicode characters so that always won't align properly. Is there a method to achieve better alignment? (yes I would prefer empty list to print out as NIL)

Thanks.

```
(progn
  (format t "~?" "~5@a ~5@a ~5@a ~5@a ~5@a~%" '(蘋果 () 桔子 () 西瓜))
  (format t "~?" "~5@a ~5@a ~5@a ~5@a ~5@a~%" '(() 茄子 () 菠菜 () 苦瓜)))

OUTPUT (Column not aligned even column width has already been specified 
   蘋果   NIL    桔子   NIL    西瓜
  NIL    茄子   NIL    菠菜   NIL

Would be expecting OUTPUT aligned like below (with NIL occupy the same width as specified) :
 
   蘋果   NIL    桔子   NIL   西瓜
   NIL   茄子    NIL   菠菜   NIL
```

Comment: I think this is very implementation-dependent: neither implementation I've tried (LW and CCL both on the Mac) get it right.  The problem seems to be that the witch of characters like `蘋` &c is not what the thing expects (so if you try a row of mixed latin-1 and `nil`s it *does* work OK).  I'm not sure if `format` is *meant* to be able to deal with non-fixed-width-character sets.

Comment: I would say that format does exactly what it is supposed to do here: align to columns of 5 characters each.  It cannot know about font metrics.

Answer (score 2):

I observed that the string formatting of `()` to `NIL` takes 3 characters, where the others take 2, so I tried changing the `()` padding to `~6@a`. It turns out it works better:

```lisp
(length (format nil "~a" nil))
3

(progn
  (format t "~?" "~5@a ~6@a ~5@a ~6@a ~5@a~%" '(蘋果 () 桔子 () 西瓜))
  (format t "~?" "~6@a ~5@a ~6@a ~5@a ~6@a~%" '(() 茄子 () 菠菜 () 苦瓜)))
   蘋果    NIL    桔子    NIL    西瓜
   NIL    茄子    NIL    菠菜    NIL
```

The width of latin and non-latin characters are different (see last column specifically), but the columns look aligned now.

So, you have to pre-calculate the padding for each entry.

You can use the `~v` directive to insert a variable *inside* a directive .

```lisp
(let ((padding 30))
    (format nil "~va" padding "foo"))
;; "foo                           "
```

(source: [Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#formatting-a-format-string))

Comment: This 'fixes' the problem, but the reasoning is entirely wrong.  In particular the problem is *not* that `"NIL"` is 3 characters while `"蘋果"` is 2: it's that `"蘋果"` takes more horizontal space than `format` can know.

Comment: Indeed. I edited my first sentence (with "it turns out") to try to not convey such reasoning.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. While  the fix is fine for relatively few columns (eg. 5 cols) what appears to be aligned would mal-align again when there are more columns, said, after 7 or 8 columns, the little bit 'error' will accumulate enough for the there-after columns to be not aligned again. So the fixes works for only relative few columns.  One would also need to add code to check for every row which column values are NULL, this seems to be a little too much overhead for a otherwise very simple formatting code (fixed column width no matter what unicode character is inside)